# How to retain button state after being pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click one of the buttons (forgot your code? or tick box), they display solid red colour and lead to a different activity. When I return to the previous activity, the button state has changed to default and is displaying orange colour. How do I retain the button's original state after being pressed?

**Screenshots :**
[image]

[image]

**button_state.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#FF0D00" android:endColor="#FF0D00"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FF0D00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#D8D8D8" android:endColor="#848484" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".SignInScreen"
    android:background="#619ec9"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hello! Welcome to MLAD!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_x="-28dp"
        android:layout_y="117dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Please enter your 4 digit code:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/codeEntry"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:layout_x="5dp"
        android:layout_y="182dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <ImageButton

        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/tick"
        android:src="@drawable/black_tick"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:layout_x="120dp"
        android:layout_y="296dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codeEntry"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:src="@drawable/question"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:layout_x="232dp"
        android:layout_y="4dp" />

    <EditText
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="15"
        android:id="@+id/codeEntry"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_x="19dp"
        android:layout_y="246dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:hint="Enter Your Code Here"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create a new account"
        android:id="@+id/create_acc"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tick"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tick"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"

        android:layout_x="3dp"
        android:layout_y="410dp"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/recover_code" />

    <Button
        android:onClick="goSecActivity"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:text="Forgot your code?"
        android:id="@+id/recover_code"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tick"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tick"
        android:layout_x="222dp"
        android:layout_y="376dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/mlad_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/help"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:alpha="0.1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for the lifetime of the application even after its destroyed then used a sharedPreference to remember the state. Set it before you leave to the other activity.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
prefs.edit().putBoolean("red", true).apply();
```

that gets called right before you go to the new activity.

then have a if statement in your onResume code to do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
boolean shouldBeRed=prefs.getBoolean("red",false)

if(shouldBeRed){
//change button to red here
}
```

but if you just need it while the user is in the app(so per session), just set a flag in onStop() and then in onResume() change the buttons color accordingly.

UPDATE: NOW i understand your issue the buttons state was not changing back to grey which is the normal state.  Try removing this onelines from the button in your xml layout:

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

So make your button layout now look like this:

```
 <Button
    android:onClick="goSecActivity"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:text="Forgot your code?"
    android:id="@+id/recover_code"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tick"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_state"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tick"
    android:layout_x="222dp"
    android:layout_y="376dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    />
```

whats occurring is every time you return to the page since your focusable in touch mode its making the button focusable which is calling the focus state of your button_state.xml

from the docs:

> focusableInTouchMode: Boolean that controls whether a view can take focus while in touch mode. If this is true for a view, that view can gain focus when clicked on, and can keep focus if another view is clicked on that doesn't have this attribute set to true.

Comment: I'm  a beginner. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: first tell me, do you want the state to be remembered after after user restarts the phone and goes back into your app ?

Comment: yes i do. The button state should be programmed according to the xml file

Comment: oh, i may have misunderstood your issue. So first when you start the app the button is red, then the user clicks the button and it turns orange, now when user returns to the app the button stays orange but you want it to go back red. is that correct ?

Comment: no the button is grey, when pressed it is red. when returning to the app, the button should be grey and when it is pressed it is red.

Comment: what folder is button_state.xml in.  Also can you show the xml file for the layout or at least for the button itself, i need to know where your referencing the orange color.

Comment: it is in drawable folder. I added the layout file now.

Comment: i updated my answer. try removing this lines :  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: i have made the changes but it does not fix the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96831/discussion-between-j2emanue-and-rob-neal).